# How to set an instance of base class as attribute of child class?

Tags: python

I am trying to set an instance of base class (Human) as attribute (baby) of child class (Mother) but got unexpected behavior.
In my example I was expecting `print(mother.baby.name)` to print `Tom`.

How can I set an instance of base class as attribute of child class?

I am pretty sure I need deeper understanding of classes in python but what am I missing here?

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name):
        Human.name = name

class Mother(Human):
    def __init__(self, name_mother, name_baby):
        Mother.baby = Human(name_baby)
        Human.__init__(self, name_mother)

mother = Mother("Mary", "Tom")

print(mother.name)
print(mother.baby.name)
```

Output:

```
Mary
Mary
```

Note: Am using Python 3.5.2

Comment: If this is purely for learning purposes, great! If there are other purposes involved, I suggest to lookup "composition over inheritance".

Comment: thanks, I will take a look at "composition over inheritance" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem**

You are setting the names on the *`type`* of the object that is being initialized.

After `mother = Mother("Mary", "Tom")` the attribute `Human.name` has been set to `'Mary'` via line 2 of `Mother.__init__`.

Neither the instance `mother` nor `mother.baby` has the attribute `name`:

```
>>> vars(mother)
>>> {}
>>> vars(mother.baby)
>>> {}
```

Additionally, the class `Mother` lacks the attribute as well:

```
>>> 'name' in vars(Mother)
>>> False
```

The attribute `name` has only been set on the *class* `Human`:

```
>>> vars(Human)['name']
>>> 'Mary'
```

Thus, `mother.name` falls back to `Human.name` because the attribute `name` cannot be found on the instance `mother` or the class `Mother`. (Python tries to search the base classes for an appropriate attribute when lookup on the instance and on the class level fails.)

`mother.baby.name` also falls back to `Human.name` because `name` cannot be found in the instance `mother.baby`, but on the class of that instance (`Human`).

---

**How to fix it**

You want to set the attribute on the *instance* (`self`) here.

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Mother(Human):
    def __init__(self, name_mother, name_baby):
        self.baby = Human(name_baby)
        super().__init__(name_mother)

mother = Mother("Mary", "Tom")

print(mother.name)
print(mother.baby.name)
```

Output:

```
Mary
Tom
```

I also changed the line

```
Human.__init__(self, name_mother)
```

to

```
super().__init__(name_mother)
```

because this avoids hardcoding the name of the base class.